# java tolowercase with using ascii code in generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying to create tolowercase method with using ascii code. I found this code:

```
public void toLowerCase(){
    for (int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++){
      char aChar = myarray[i].charAt(0);
      if (65 <= aChar && aChar<=90){
        aChar = (char)( (aChar + 32) ); 
      }
      System.out.print(aChar);
    }
}
```

But myarray is generic array so, charAt gives an error

> The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type T

How can i fix this? I try to create a new array of String and convert generic array to new array but it does not work. How can i convert generic array to string array or how can i create tolowercase method with using ascii code in generic array?

Comment: Why is your array generic? How do you know it contains strings?

Comment: i am doing homework. My implementation must be generic and I cannot use any pre-written Java Api Class. I must write my own code for data structures.

Comment: You can call `toString()` on the element to convert it to a string, assuming you know it's not null. But it seems like a very unusual requirement.

Comment: It is important by the end of your studies you know that Java `char` does _not_ represent an ASCII value. Someone must think it'll help you to learn about ASCII first but I'll bet that they won't finish the job. Your function converts [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) letters to lowercase per English rules. Those letters are also in the ASCII character set so a simple—more accurate—name for the function would be `toLowerCaseIfAscii` so it's clearly not a promise to convert all 109591 letters to lowercase. Also, it's far easier to read 65 as `'A'`; 90 as `'Z'`

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's a class or interface which has a `charAt` method you have nothing to call. What you can do is make your generic type `T extends CharSequence` and you will be able to use `charAt` as the  `CharSequence` interface has this method.

Classes which implement CharSequence include String, StringBuffer and StringBuilder.

> How can i convert generic array to string array or how can i create tolowercase method with using ascii code in generic array?

You can do this

```
T[] myarray = {"to", "be", "or", "not", "TO", "be"};
String[] strs = (String[]) myarray;
```

though it would be much simpler to do

```
String[] myarray = {"to", "be", "or", "not", "TO", "be"};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what should do your job:

```
char myarray[] = {'A','F'};
int arraySize = 2;
for (int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++){
     char aChar = myarray[i];
     if (65 <= aChar && aChar<=90){
        aChar = (char)( (aChar + 32) ); 
     }

      System.out.print(aChar);
    }
 }
```

Why do you need the `charAt()`?

You are using a character array. If you use a string array then you can try to use that.

For a String array you can do something like this(if you don't want to use `toLowerCase()`):

```
public static void toLowerCaseString(){

    String myStringArray[] = {"Something","Nothing"}; 

    for (int i = 0; i<myStringArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< myStringArray[i].length(); j++){
             char aChar = myStringArray[i].charAt(j);

             if (65 <= aChar && aChar<=90){
                aChar = (char)( (aChar + 32) ); 
             }
             System.out.print(aChar);
        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: for example my array occures T[] myarray = {"to", "be", "or", "not", "TO", "be"} so I need charAt()

Comment: @javajava You will need to change it to a `String[]` and then use it.